# Infinitive of an -se verb

Tags: reflexivos, infinitivo

I came across this sentence from a book:

> Hoy tenemos mucho estrés; es mejor tener calma que *desesperar**se***.

Why isn't it *desesperar**nos***? I think it should be -nos because I have also seen

> No debemos *desesperar**nos***.

Is there a subtle difference between [inf.] in "deber de [inf.]" and "es mejor [inf.] que [inf.]" that I do not know about, or is the book just wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

"Es mejor tener calma que preocuparse" is a general statement. The subject, preocuparse, is impersonal (not referring to any surviving person) and if we used *nos* instead, we'd be specifying someone.

Now, there's nothing wrong doing that. You can absolutely say *es mejor tener calma que preocuparnos*, but there you have a personal infinitive with a matching reflexive pronoun. Note that this structure may sound agrammatical to some Spanish speakers, but it is accepted. The most common –and universal— way to specify a subject is to use a subordinate clause: *es mejor que tengamos calma que que nos preocupemos* (the double *que* is not a typo — one is for the comparison, the other is the relative pronoun).

Compare that to *no debemos preocuparnos*. The infinitive there necessarily refers to us, it cannot be impersonal, and therefore must use *nos*. Consider too the proclitic form: *no nos debemos preocupar*, clearly, using *se* there doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you! So the difference between "Es mejor [...] que [...]" and "No debemos [...]" is semantic. I imagine that even if I try to say "It is better *for us* to [...] than to [...]", the infinitive in [...] should still be impersonal, and -se should be used instead of -nos, right? (Can I put "Es mejor para nosotros [...] que [...]" or would that be weird?)